# List 'minus' an item

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just as you can write

```
L + [item]
```

to add an item to a list in the form of a copied list, can you do a similar thing but with subtraction as

```
L - [item]
```

doesn't work?

Comment: Nitpick: `L + [item]` doesn't add `item` to `L`. It creates a shallow copy of `L` with `item` at the end. To add an item to `L`, you use `L.append(item)`. To remove an item, you use `L.remove(item)`.

Comment: Yes I realise this, I am merely after a method of creating a similar copy of L, but this time without a specific item...

Answer (score 6):

Since `L + [item]` creates a *new* list, to create a new list with an item removed, use a list comprehension:

```
L = [value for value in L if value != item]
```

This would remove *all* values in `L` equal to `item`. To remove the last element, use slicing:

```
L = L[:-1]
```

which creates a new list without the last index.

Using `del L[index]` or `L.remove(item)` would remove values from a list *in-place*, which is not quite the same as `L + [item]`.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the element *by value*, use [`L.remove(x)`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).  This modify the collecions in-place.

To remove *by index*, do `del L[i]` (again, modification is done in-place).

If it's the subtraction syntax you're after, it can be done with `set`s (will create and return a new set):

```
set([1,6,9]) - set([6])
```

Comment: `set.remove` is closer to `list.remove` in that both raise an exception if `x` is not present (`discard` silently ignores that). That's usually less likely to hide bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list.remove(element) to remove an element from a list ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)):

```
x = [1,2,3]

x.remove(3)

print(x) # [1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it would make sense only if the list ends with same sublist (if you expect that `L - [item]` should remove the item from the end of the list, the same way as `L + [item]` adds an item to the end.).

```
L[:-1]
```

should work just fine

I am not suggesting you to use `del` or `list.remove`, because it would modify the list in place, while your example creates a new list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list with a subtraction operator, you can easily write it:

```
class SubtractableList(list):
    """A list that supports the subtraction operator.

    For example:

    >>> l = SubtractableList([1, 2, 3])
    >>> l - [3]
    [1, 2]
    >>> l -= [2]
    >>> SubtractableList(range(5)) - l
    [0, 2, 4]

    """
    def __sub__(self, other):
        try:
            other = set(other)
        except TypeError:       # some item in other is not hashable
            pass                # so fall back to quadratic algorithm
        return type(self)(item for item in self if item not in other)
```